# How to distinguish if useEffect is triggered by route change

Tags: reactjs, react-router

As I know useEffect can be triggered by the following conditions

1. dependencies change
2. Route change
3. Initial render

I have the following component, `data` is a complex object. When it is triggered by route change, the `data` prop has the cached value. Everything else such as state, ref get reset.

```
const App = memo(({ data }}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
     // if triggered by route change, do thing
     
  }, [data]);

  return (<div />)
});
```

What is the best way to distinguish if useEffect invoked by route change?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put `location` as a dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // ...
}, [location]);
```

**edit**
If you want to *exclude* this dependency, you can do:

```
const [flag, setFlag] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    setFlag(false);
}, [location]);

useEffect(async () => {
    await setTimeout(() => undefined, 500); //sleep to wait for other useEffect() to set a flag or not
    
    if (flag) { /* do sth that is not invoked by a location change */ }
    else {
        setFlag(true);
    }
}, [data]);
```

**edit2**

I've looked it up in the official docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state

This way you can construct a `componentDidUpdate(prevProps)` hook, so your code would look sth like:

```
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}

useEffect(() => {
    const prevLocation = usePrevious(location);

    if (location === prevLocation)
        //the body of your function
}, [data]);
```

Comment: Just tested it still get triggered by route change.

Comment: @user3908406 Ok, I understood that you DO want to trigger it on a location change... Excluding a dependency in useEffect() is not that straightforward, but I've added it inside an edit to my answer, you can give it a try.

Comment: Upvoted you. Thanks. Still looking for better solution. one that does not need another useEffect or state or ref would be great, since I need to do this in lots of component

Comment: I tried this approach before, but when route changes, usePrevious ref will reset, so prevLocation will be undefined.

Comment: I think that it happens only when you refresh the browser (or manually type the path in the address field), and that's a thing React doesn't control by definition (although maybe you'd find some workaround on the web).